# Does ijab chat only work with Apache server?

Tags: xmpp, chat, tomcat6

The question is about `ijab` (facebook, gmail style chat bar) chat.
I have seen [this](http://code.google.com/p/ijab/wiki/iJabWithOpenfire) tutorial for configuring `ijab` with Openfire XMPP server
but not able to connect it with Openfire server.

In the tutorial `ijab` is being used with Apache webserver but I am using Tomcat with `urlrewritefilter` for redirecting my request to Openfire server.

Does `ijab` chat only work with Apache server?
Is there any way of using `ijab` chat with other web servers like Tomcat, Weblogic, jboss etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think It will only work in Apache since it requires mode_rewrite configuration.

Comment: i think mode_rewrite is only used for redirecting http request to xmpp server and i have used urlrewritefilter for that purpose and my request is also being redirect to xmpp server but not able to connect.